azure : build pipeline dependent branch
On azure, I have 3 branches :

dev
release
master

I created 3 build pipelines, one per branch. Each pipeline gets the sources from his specific branch and creates each on artefact.
For the deployment, I created 3 release deployment.
All theses pipelines are classic pipeline.
Everything is working great.
But I want to simplify this process.
For these 3 branches, in classic mode, How can I make just ONE build pipeline and ONE release pipeline for this (no 3 build and release pipelines)? Is is possible?

TL;DR yes, it is possible to have only one build pipeline and only one release pipeline.
Build pipeline
You can manually choose the branch when queuing a new build:

Or, as an alternative, you can enable continuous integration and set up multiple branch builds for your repository:

Remember to set a meaningful name to your build pipeline, ideally containing the branch name to avoid deploying the wrong artifacts when running the release pipeline:

See:

Build multiple branches in Azure Pipelines for more details
Configure run or build numbers

Release pipeline
When creating or configuring the release pipeline you can configure to use an artifact from the build pipeline like this:

And then, when creating a new release, you can choose which artifact to deploy :

Or, as an alternative, configure a continuous deployment trigger based on the branch:


Thanks. When you select the 3 branches in the "branch filters", is this setting cancels the "Get Source" setting (first step of the task) ?

@Totoblo no - in that section you define the default branch for manual and scheduled builds. You can always choose which branch you want to use when you queue a build manually.

@Totoblo in the Triggers section you define the branches in which changes will trigger automatically the build.

Let me edit my answer to clarify that part

@Totoblo please refresh the page. I hope my explanation is clearer now.

Ok. It is clearer now. And if I want to automate this process (when I merge a branch to another i want to trigger ci and cd) is it working ?

@Totoblo added more details


I want to simplify this process. For these 3 branches, in classic mode, How can I make just ONE build pipeline and ONE release pipeline for this (no 3 build and release pipelines)? Is is possible?

It's possible. You can use custom condition to distinguish different jobs. Details below：
For build classic pipeline:

You can use eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/branchname') as custom condition:



You can enable CI trigger on different branches.


If you run the build on different branch, it will run the specific job based on the name.

For release classic pipeline:

Still monitor on the build artifact as trigger.


Add custom conidtion eq(variables['Release.Artifacts.{alias}.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/dev')to validate the artifact source branch, to run the jobs for specific branch.



It will only run target branch jobs in release, skip others to make sure it has correct deployment.

Please note individual CI/CD could be more simple and have clear logic, please consider the best way to design your build and release due to your situation.
